# C++ variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, containers, variadic

I am trying to create a polymorhic container working with variadic templates.
Container is initialized as

```
container<tag, std::string, int, int, int> m;
```

I want to use following syntax:

```
auto& v2 = m.find<2, 3, 4>(255, 0, 0);
```

Template arguments would specify "columns" and for parameters, I want appropriate type to be expected by compiler.

For one template argument (`find<2>(255)`) I used:

```
template < int idx > const typename value_type & 
find( const typename std::tuple_element<idx, typename value_type>::type &key) {
  const std::size_t row_id = getId<idx>(key);
  return data_.at(row_id);
}
```

That worked perfectly, so I wanted to expand it as follows:

```
template<int ... idx> const typename value_type & 
find(const typename std::tuple_element<idx..., typename value_type>::type &keys...) {
  const std::size_t row_id = getId<idx...>(keys);
  return data_.at(row_id);
}
```

What's not working at all. Compilation error C2660 - find: function does not take 3 arguments. Can someone explain me, what am I missing here? 
Thanks.

EDIT:

Header of `container` class is

```
template<typename ... Arguments> class container
```

`value_type`mentioned is

```
typedef std::tuple < Arguments... > value_type;
```

EDIT2:
T.C.'s answer was indeed useful, though I'm still crawling through my bugs with variadic templates. Currently:

```
enum tag {/*...*/}

int main() {
  container<tag, std::string, int, int, int> m;
}

template<typename ... Arguments> class container {
 public:
  typedef std::tuple < Arguments... > value_type;
  std::vector<value_type> data_;

  template <int id> void narrowRange(
    std::set<std::size_t> & range, 
    const typename std::tuple_element<id, typename value_type>::type &key)
  {
    // all commented out
  }

  template <int id, int ... idx>
  void narrowRange(
    std::set<std::size_t> & range, 
    const typename std::tuple_element<id, typename value_type>::type & key, 
    const typename std::tuple_element<idx, typename value_type>::type & ... keys) // <-
  {
    narrowRange<idx...>(range, keys...);
    // rest commented out
  }
```

Will invoke internal error in MSVS2013 on the marked line. Any suggestions why would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First, `value_type` doesn't need `typename` - I'm fairly sure the grammar actually bans it.

Second, you are expanding `idx` too early, and also incorrectly attempting to expand `keys` in the declaration. (That second `...` is actually being parsed as a C-style varargs.) You are also not expanding the pack `keys` in the function body. Assuming that you want `find<2, 3, 4>(255, 0, 0)` to call `getId<2, 3, 4>(255, 0, 0)`, the correct syntax is

```
template<int ... idx> const value_type & 
find(const typename std::tuple_element<idx, value_type>::type &... keys) {
  const std::size_t row_id = getId<idx...>(keys...);
  return data_.at(row_id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. However, I got issue, which looks very familiar: `template < int ... idx> void erase(const typename std::tuple_element<idx, value_type>::type & ... keys) {
  const std::size_t row_id = getId<idx...>(keys...);
  /* etc. */}` failing on "does not contain a parameter pack" and I really have no clue why - as it looks same as the previous function to me

Comment: @eghuro Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an edit to your question.